# How to bind source to plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I want to bind source to eclipse plugin.

I have created custom target from eclipse indigo update site and there are plugins with source code, so I tried to make such source plugin for egit plugin. I don't know how to make such plugin using eclipse, so I just took manifest from existing source plugin and updated it with egit specific information.

Then I added this plugin to my custom target platform. However despite plugin is added I still can not access source code of classes from egit.ui plugin.

There is following manifest I created for source plugin:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Eclipse-SourceBundle: org.eclipse.egit.ui;version="1.3.0.201202151440-r"
 ;roots="."
Bundle-Vendor: Eclipse Project
Bundle-Name: EGit Source
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.egit.ui.source;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.3.0.201202151440-r
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
```

And plugin file itself I uploaded to dropbox: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14767221/org.eclipse.egit.ui.source_1.3.0.201202151440-r.jar

What is wrong with current source plugin? How can it be fixed? What is easier fix this plugin or generate source plugin from egit source code using eclipse?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Open the view Plug-ins in Eclipse,Right click--> Import Project as -->Source Project or Project from repository.You would be able to see this plugin package in Your Project Explorer.

Comment: @Eshika, thanks that worked! However today I found software site (http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates) with egit source, dont know why that did not happen yesterday.

Comment: @Eshika, moreover I do not remember how I included egit into target definition :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to import source as proposed Eshika: [How to bind source to plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323996/how-to-bind-source-to-plugin#comment13300918_10323996)

I solved this problem by importing source code plugin from software site along with ordinary plugin that contains binary code.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes is also good to have a decompiler in your "toolbox" if you want to have a quick look without adding sources or simply doesn't have source code. I use: http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdeclipse installed on eclipse 3.7.2.